# Why doesn't event.target.value include "." and "e" for number inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, preact

I'm using Preact:

```
<input type="number" onKeyup={event => console.log(event.target.value)} />
```

If I enter a period or an "e", it doesn't appear as part of `event.target.value` until I enter another digit after it.

E.g.

If the input value is `123`, `123` gets logged.

If the input value is `123.`, `123` gets logged.

If the input value is `123..`, `123` gets logged.

If the input value is `123.4`, `123.4` gets logged.

Why does it behave like this? Is there a way to get the actual input (without removing `type="number"`)?

Comment: Input type number is simply parsing 123. as the integer 123. Why do you need the period?

Comment: Because the input type is number and `123.` or `123..` is not a valid number

Comment: Not sure what people think about this, but... I personally dislike number inputs a lot! They always give a headache when you want some control over them. My suggestion is to use a "normal" input and add a regex that only allows numbers (and decimals if u want that).

Comment: @Chris I agree, I think I'll just use `text` input instead, otherwise I'll need a lot of `number`-specific logic.

Answer (score 2):

The `number` input can hold integers as well as floating point numbers.

Since `123.` is an integer, the input will return the integer `123`

Also `123.4` is a valid floating point number so the input will have a value of `123.4`

There is no way to return strings such as `123.4` from a number input type because it is not meant to be used for that.

Comment: Regardless of what magic auto formatting JS does, there should be a way to get the exact input that was typed.

Comment: According to W3: "User agents must not allow the user to set the value to a non-empty string that is not a valid floating point number". So no there is not :) more info here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/number-state.html#number-state

Answer (score 0):

the point is that e is an expression e² is the same like e2, without any digit after e it is incomplete and the number won´t changed, so "e" isn't saved.

Same with the point. A number with point at the end is the number itself, so it won´t be saved.

You have to change it to text or your "e" at the last of this row isn't saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the default value in a variable and update that variable after each keyup event.

example
HTML

```
<input type="number" onKeyup={event => this.eachKeyPress(event)} />
```

JS

```
let output = "";
function eachKeyPress(event){
  output += event.key;
  console.log("value : ",output );   
}
```